# Android Draw on top of an EditText, Spinner or Button (Draw on Screen)

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-widget

what I want to achieve is this:

[image]

As you can see there is are two tiny, yellow triangles (warning signs) in the EdiTtexts. I read, it's possible to achieve that by using Relative layout and simply have the images overlap the EditText. This however is not an option as I am writing a library project and can't limit the user to one particular layout type (such as RelativeLayout). Alternatively I read, it can be done in the onDraw method of a view. However, I will have no access to the onDraw method (or rather now way of overriding it). The one thing I have access to, is the Views itslef (like Spinner, EditText) or alternatively their wrapping view (Like LinearLayout etc...). I need to set this tiny icon not only on EditText but generally on Views such as Spinner, Button, EditText, etc....

One idea was to simply obtain the x/y coordinates of the View on which I want to draw that warning sign, but although I am able to get the coordinates I am quite at a loss as to how to actually do the drawing on the obtained view.

On an additional note: I am using code to generate the layout from non-android layout-xml files. That only matters in so far, that I am afraid android-layout-xml-based solutions are not an option. Furthermore I have to be able to dynamically add/remove those image overlays.

Please let me know, if there are further questions.

Thank you very much in advance & Best regards,
Ready4Android

**EDIT**

I had one idea but I am not sure how to carry it out: I could determine the on-screen coordinates of my Widgets (like Spinner, EditText, Button...) and then I could draw that little warning symbol on top of my canvas - without even touching the Widgets. So would it be easier to solve, if I just wanted to draw on the screen? It should be possible, non?

**EDIT 2** (20.09)

I followed the advice from superM but since the Icon was stretched I tried to use a bitmap inside the item. Thing is: It places the icon at the correct place (left edge) but the skin of the button disappears - I guess because it's replaced by the bitmap...

Here is the original Button:

[image]

Here the Xml (the invisible shape is the same as in superM's post):

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/sign_warning_overlay_shape"
        android:top="5dip" android:right="5dip" android:bottom="5dip"
        android:left="5dip" />
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/sign_warning" android:gravity="left" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and this is how it looks:

[image]

With the original posted layer list by superM - this one:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/sign_warning_overlay_shape"
        android:top="5dip" android:right="5dip" android:bottom="5dip"
        android:left="5dip" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/sign_warning" android:top="5dip"
        android:right="5dip" android:bottom="5dip" android:left="5dip" />
</layer-list>
```

the Button looks like this(seems like here too the icon replaces the button skin):

[image]

Could it be, that I am setting the layer list in a wrong way? What would be the correct code to set the layer list on a button? I am using this one:

```
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sign_warning_overlay_layer_list);
```

**Edit 3 - Modified solution**

This edit is based on the accepted answer - I decided to go for a bitmap embedded in an item because I had issues with the image being stretched - here is the layer_list:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/btn_default"
        android:top="5dip" android:right="5dip" android:bottom="5dip"
        android:left="5dip" />
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/sign_warning" android:gravity="left" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Which can be set on the button like this:
    button.setBackgroundDrawable(button.getResources().getDrawable(                 R.drawable.layer_list));

and produces the following result:

[image]

That's it folks :) !

Thanks for all the suggestions & Cheers,

Ready4Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For editText it is editText.setCompoundDrawables(left, top, right, bottom) where left, top, right and bottom are either drawables or null. For buttons you can set the image as background by using a layer-list and shape, where the first layer is transparent and should "wrap" your button and the second layer is the image. This is can be done with other views too.

Here's an example of layer-list with transparent background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:drawable="@android:drawable/btn_default" <!--any default background from android:drawable-->
        android:top="5dip"
        android:right="5dip"
        android:bottom="5dip"
        android:left="5dip" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/my_drawable"
        android:top="0dip"
        android:right="0dip"
        android:bottom="0dip"
        android:left="0dip" />
</layer-list>
```

where `background_transparent` is:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid 
        android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <padding 
        android:top="0dip"
        android:left="3dip" 
        android:bottom="5dip"
        android:right="3dip" />
    <corners 
        android:radius="4dip" /> 
</shape>
```

Answer (score 2):

In the case you mentioned, I think that what you want can be easily done by setting [android:drawableLeft](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3adrawableLeft).

Comment: As far as I am aware this is equal to the method setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds which is only available in TextView and EditText - or am i mistaken here? I edited my question so that it is now more clear, that I need to set this icon on Views in general - not just EditTexts, but also Buttons, Spinner etc....

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion though - grrr I surpassed the 5-minutes edit limit for my previous comment :)

Comment: Oh yes you're right - but I am afraid Spinner is not a TextView :/ that means the solution does not work for all Widgets... Any idea for a Spinner?

Answer (score 0):

## Buttons:

Simply set the text

- using code:

  ```
  button.setText("<img src=\"image_location\"/>Login");
  ```
- using xml:

  ```
  android:text="@string/mystring"
  //mystring must be a string in strings.xml
  //with a value of <img src="image_location"/>Login
  ```

## EditTexts:

Your question is not clear 100%...

If you want the image to be behind the text, then the best way to achieve this is by setting a background with that image to the left and let it be a 9patch image that extends the empty space.

If you want the image to move to the right with the text entered, then you have a couple of ways to achieve it, one simple would be to use a listener to the text input and always make sure there is an  at the end of the text. I have not tested this approach but I guess it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - I'll try to explain what I want: I want to be able to draw that yellow triangly on pretty much ANY widget (not just buttons, edittexts or spinners) - ideally on the left corner of the widget (as seen in the picture). The purpose of the yellow triangle is to indicate, that that Widget's content is currently invalid.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to be able to place arbitrary views over anything, you can take a look at [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) and use [View.getLocationInWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationInWindow%28int%5B%5D%29) to get co-ordinates for the views you want to overlay. You can take a look at an android standard usage for putting a little error marker floating over a textview in [TextView.setError](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/android/widget/TextView.java#TextView.setError%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Comment: Hello & Thank you very much for ur suggestion! A question about PopupWindow: Isnt a popup window usually modal? If thats the case, it would not be an option, as those icons are just "decoration" and should not block the current activity. I'll try out ur suggestion asap - thanks again!

Comment: I tried the popup stuff - funny enough: Location seems to be wrong (neither getLocationOnScreen nor getLocationInWindow seem to be giving the correct widget location. And the popup icon is floating - it does not scroll if I scroll the dialog - its on the left corner in the middle of the screen and it stays there - even if i scroll oO ...